# ASP.NET 5 project packages clenaup

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I am using latest nightly build during developmant of my ASP.NET 5 project and faced following issue.

During publishing I have all previous versions of packages published instead of just latest (that are specified in project.json).

So if I previously used `"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta1"`, `"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta2"`, `"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1"` I'll get all of them published to `publish_folder\approot\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc`.

How can I avoid publishing packages that are not used in the project anymore?

Comment: I believe, by removing them from the directory, or from the `project.json` file. Once done, remove those assemblies from the bin folder and publish the website.

Comment: I'm using latest version in project.json config file. From example above, it's "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1". I don't think I should create a script that will manually delete old packages, that should be done automatically somehow.

Comment: I'd need to try this out with the tooling, but by default the command line tool that VS calls to pack your application doesn't clean out the destination. So if you deploy to a different location you shouldn't see all the old packages. The UI should have an option to clean out the destination, but I don't have VS working at the moment to see why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no issues anymore, I believe this bug fixed by Microsoft already. I've upgraded KVM to latest RC version as well as all packages in the project. To install and upgrade KVM and KRE do the following:

1. Open PowerShell as Administrator
2. Run command: "Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned" and confirm changes, this will allow execution of PowerShell scripts
3. Clone https://github.com/aspnet/Home repository (in my case it's D:\GitHub\Home)
4. in PowerShell console navigate to D:\GitHub\Home and run "kvminstall.ps1"
5. Change default feed URL to dev branch to use latest packages

   a. Open "kvm.ps1" for editing

   b. Go to line 41 and set feed url: $feed = "https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2";

If you skip previous step, you will get beta1 version of packages (on time of writing this post) instead of release candidate

6. Open command promt (Windows -> Run -> cmd)
7. Navigate to D:\GitHub\Home
8. Run "kvm upgrade" (it will download latest version of KRE x86 and set it as default
9. Run "kvm up upgrade -amd64" to do the same for x64 packages version